# Can any one tell me how to show recyclerview in fragment using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

I want to display data with recyclerview in a fragment. I able to show the data in an activity but using the same code in a fragment, it does not work.

This is the adapter

```
class chatAdapter (val chatlist: ArrayList<ChatData>): RecyclerView.Adapter<chatAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return chatlist.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val chat: ChatData = chatlist[position]

    holder?.textViewName?.text = chat.doctorName
    holder?.textViewMessage?.text = chat.lastMessage
    holder?.textViewTime?.text = chat.timeStamp
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val textViewName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.docName)
    val textViewMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastMsg)
    val textViewTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timestamp)
}
}
```

the data class:

```
package com.example.myapplication

data class ChatData( val doctorName: String, val lastMessage: String , val timeStamp: String)
```

The code of fragment where I want help:

```
class ConsultFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consult, container, false)

    //This code is Unreachable in the fragment but it works perfectly fine in activity
    val recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.docrecview)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val docs = ArrayList<DocData>()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

       val id = item.itemId
        if (id==R.id.consult)
        {
            activity?.let{
                val intent = Intent (it, doctors::class.java)
                it.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

//        when (item.itemId) {
//            R.id.Consult -> {
//                activity?.let {
//                    val intent = Intent (this@ConsultFragment.context, DocListFragment::class.java)
//                    startActivity(intent)
//                }
//            }
//        }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you're talking about won't be executed becouse it is placed after return.
You can get View from inlate function and return it after your code for recycler view